# Show that $M(3)$ of metric axioms can be replaced by a weaker axiom $M'(3)$

Tags: proof-verification, logic, metric-spaces, axioms

$M(3):=\text{ For all $x,y,z \in X$, $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$}$

$M'(3):= \text { If $x,y,z \in X$ are distinct, then $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$}$. [all the other axioms are identical]

Proof:

To show, $M(3) \implies M'(3)$:  $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y)+d(y,z) \quad  \forall x, y, z\in X \implies d(x,z) \leq d(x,y)+d(y,z) \quad \forall x \neq y \neq z \neq x \in X $

To show, $M'(3) \implies M(3):$ $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y)+d(y,z) \quad \forall x\neq y\neq z \neq x$. The other axioms remaining identical, we resolve the rest of the cases.

When $x=y=z$, implication holds since $LHS=0$.

When $x=y \neq z$, inequality holds.

When $x =z \neq y $ and when $x \neq y=z$ , the inequality holds. Thereby

$ M(1) \land M(2) \land M'(3) \implies M(1) \land M(2) \land M(3)$ and

$M(3) \implies M'(3) \implies M(1) \land M(2) \land M(3) \implies M(1) \land M(2) \land M'(3)$

So, $M(3)$ can be replaced by the weaker $M'(3)$.

Is this correct? Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems to me you can trim this to: Case 1: $x=z$ (in this case we are done since left-hand-side is zero); Case 2: $x\neq z$ (now consider the three possibilities $y=x$, $y=z$, $y \notin \{x,z\}$). Anyway, your case $x=y\neq z$ likely needs more explanation than "inequality holds." [also, your expression $\forall x \neq y \neq z \neq x$ is unclear.]

Comment: @Michael, thank you for the response. When $x=y \neq z$, $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y)+d(y,z) \implies d(x,z) \leq d(x,z)$ since by $M(2), d(x,y)=0$. The unclear expression:  $ \forall \  x \neq y, y \neq z, z \neq x$. Is it better?

Comment: Looks good (though I don't know what M(1) and M(2) are].  For the unclear expression you could also just say "if $x, y, z$ are distinct."

Comment: $M(1):= d(x,y) \geq 0$, and $d(x,y)=0 $ iff $x=y$, $\forall  \ x, y \in X$. 

$M(2):= d(x,y)= d(y,x),  \ \forall x, y \in X$. ($X$ being a non-empty set in all cases)

Comment: In the previous reply, it should be $M(1)$, by which $d(x,y)=0$.